# Kohanа_Template before()

Tags: php-frameworks, kohana

Превет .Посмотрел документацию http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/api/Controller_Template увидел что Controller_Template отличается от Controller только методами before/after...
Не совсем понял как их использовать..Можно мини пример?

Есдинственное наткнулся на статью http://fuelphp-framework.ru/general/controllers/template.html но мне она не сильно помогла...

Начну с того,что создал класс

```
class Controller_My extends Controller {

public function after()
{
    echo 'after';
}
public function before()
{
    echo 'before';
}
    public function action_index()
    {
            $view = View::factory('....');
            $this->response->body($view);

    }
}
```

Как я понял они автоматом загружаются.Сообщения 'after' и  'before' выводятся,но почему after вывод идет до вывода шаблона?

Comment: Напишите, что несовсем понятно? В статье, с поправкой на то, что это ``FuelPHP``, всё довольно неплохо написно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вывод из `after()` идёт до шаблона, т.к. вывод шаблона происходит гораздо позже. См. последние строчки из [index.php](https://github.com/kohana/kohana/blob/3.3/master/index.php#L117)

```
echo Request::factory(TRUE, array(), FALSE) // 1. создали запрос (Request)
    ->execute() // 2. выполнили и вернули Response
    ->send_headers(TRUE) // 3. проставили заголовки
    ->body(); // 4. вернули и вывели содержимое
```

Вообще, не стоит делать вывод или установку заголовков прямо в контроллере, т.к. это сработает в т.2 и может помешать тем же заголовкам в т.3.

*Если добавите `echo` в `action`, то порядок будет верным: before, action, after*

Comment: Полезно....Благодарен

Answer (score 1):

методы `before()` И `after()` необязательны для использования. Использовать их нужно только если в этих методах вы делаете ещё что-то, глобально меняете `title` для данного контроллера, например.

Comment: "..глобально меняете title для данного контроллера.."-ще к этому не дошел,поэтому не понятно...